# MathJax using Pandoc Library

Tags: haskell, mathjax, pandoc

I'm making a Haskell data type that represents mixed MathJax and Markdown.  I am using Pandoc (as a library) to handle this stuff.  I have figured out that the default ReaderOption for Pandoc will treat anything in $'s as math, as I expect.  But it seems that if I set  HTMLMathMethod to MathJax, I **have** to pass in the URL to a MathJax script.  But I already have MathJax set up to load for my site globally.  Is there a clean way to fix this, or should I just make sure I have the MathJaxes synched?

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but I use mathjax on my site and load it by myself - I just set `writerHTMLMathMethod = MathJax ""`

Comment: @rafalio:  that worked.  I was worried it would make an empty <link>, but it works great.  If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ha, thanks, some points for me :) Didn't post as an answer at first since I wasn't sure that's what you are looking for, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this as follows should make it work without you having to pass any URL

```
writerHTMLMathMethod = MathJax ""
```